# Jmeter Multiple CSV files

Tags: jmeter

I wanna use 2 CSV files. One CSV file with user id nd passwords.And second CSV file, containing data for adding different producers(agents) against  each user.
I mean user id 1 should take 1st row of producer data, user id2 shall take 2nd row of producer data and so on. IS this possible in jmeter and how?

Answer (score 0):

Put user 1, password 1 and other data in the same row which needs to be used. Make sure you CSV is having the headers and do not put any thing in the "Variable Names" of CSV Dataset config.

[image]

[image]
Now, when you run with multiple thread, 1st thread will pick 1st row and then move to the second row. Other threads will also do the same.

Hope it helps.

You can use multiple csv's but then you have to maintain login and other test data binding. So, it is better to put it in one.